# Exposing parameter types in a perfectly-forwarding function avoiding code repetition

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, dry, perfect-forwarding

I have an annoying scenario where I need to defer the initialization of some object `state` and allow the user to construct one on demand. E.g.

```
// user code

context c;
// ...do something...
c.initialize_state(a, b, c);
```

```
// library code

class context
{
private:
    class state
    {
        state(A a, B b, C c);

        state(const state&) = delete;
        state(state&&) = delete;
    };

    std::optional<state> _state; // or `boost::optional`

public:
    template <typename... Xs>
    void initialize_state(Xs&&... xs) 
    {
        _state.emplace(std::forward<Xs>(xs)...);
    }
};
```

As you can see from the code above, the interface of `context::initialize_state` tells the user *nothing* about how to initialize `context::_state`. The user is forced to look at the implementation of `initialize_state` and then look at `state::state` to understand what should be passed to `initialize_state`.

I could change `initialize_state` to...

```
void initialize_state(A&& a, B&& b, C&& c) 
{
    _state.emplace(std::move(a), std::move(b), std::move(c));
}
```

...but this has a major drawback: there is code duplication with `state::state`, that needs to be manually maintained in case the argument types change.

Is there any way I can get the best of both worlds (DRY and user-friendly interface)? Note that `state` is not movable/copyable.

Comment: a minor detail: are you sure of the c++11 tag? AFAIK std::optional is c++17.

Comment: I think this post reads more like a criticism of variadic templates in general

Comment: It's a shame `initialize_state` is a function. If it were a type, you could only declare `initialize_state<Xs...>` and fully instantiate `initialize_state<A,B,C>` in the header, and _define_ it elsewhere (in a source file for instance).

Comment: @PicaudVincent: sorry, I'm using an internal C++11 replacement for `std::optional` in this particular project.

Comment: I wouldn't really call this a "code duplication". This `initialize_state` function acts more like a façade for user.

Comment: Is `state` not movable/copyable because of some constraint on one of its members like `a`, `b` or `c`? I could see a scenario where we have a `StateCreator` class that eases things a bit.

Comment: @AndyG: yes, that's correct. `context` is also not movable itself for the same reason.

Comment: Since it appears that `a` `b` and `c` are individually movable, it sounds like maybe `state` has some other internal members that prevent movability. It sounds like encapsulation is a good approach; pull out `A` `B` and `C` into another class that can be passed in.

Comment: Couldn't you have three type aliases and use those aliases in the constructor and `initialize_state` instead? Changing the aliases then changes the types for both functions.

Comment: Do you mean literally `void initialize_state(A&& a, B&& b, C&& c)` or should they be perfectly forwarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but this has a major drawback: there is code duplication with state::state, that needs to be manually maintained in case the argument types change.

This is a general problem with encapsulation. It's (definition) not DRY.

There is a way to preserve the relationship between the `state` constructor overloads and the interface of `initialize_state`, which is to use `enable_if` along with the `is_constructible` type trait.

```
class context
{
private:
    class state
    {
    public:
        state(A a, B b, C c);

        state(const state&) = delete;
        state(state&&) = delete;
    };

    std::optional<state> _state; // or `boost::optional`
public:
    template <typename... Xs>
    auto 
    initialize_state(Xs&&... xs) 
    -> 
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        // condition
        std::is_constructible<state, Xs...>::value, 

        // return type
        void
    >
    {
        _state.emplace(std::forward<Xs>(xs)...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The class `state` may not be copyable/movable, but it appears that `A`, `B` and `C` are. (So I'm assuming there is some other, internal data in `state` that prevents copyability/movability)

You can pull these members out into another class that can be injected into `state`. For lack of a better name, I'll call it `state_args`:

```
struct state_args
{
   explicit state_args(A a, B b, C c);
   A a_;
   B b_;
   C c_;
};
```

Which enables the following:

```
class context
{
private:
    class state
    {
        state(state_args args);

        state(const state&) = delete;
        state(state&&) = delete;
    };

    std::optional<state> _state; // or `boost::optional`

public:
    template<class STATE_ARGS, /*enable_if to ensure STATE_ARGS is indeed state_args*/>
    void initialize_state(STATE_ARGS&& internal_state) 
    {
        _state.emplace(std::forward<STATE_ARGS>(internal_state));
    }
};
```

Comment: I suggest `static_assert` over SFINAE and not all caps type name because ouch.

Comment: @PasserBy: :-)  Fair enough criticisms

Answer (score 2):

Probably creating more issues than solving, you might template your class:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class context_impl
{
private:
    class state
    {
        state(Ts...);

        state(const state&) = delete;
        state(state&&) = delete;
    };

    std::optional<state> _state; // or `boost::optional`

public:
    void initialize_state(Ts&&... xs) 
    {
        _state.emplace(std::forward<Xs>(xs)...);
    }
};

using context = context_impl<A, B, C>;
```

As template are fixed by the class, `void initialize_state(Ts&&... xs)` has fixed signature (intellisense can show expected arguments for example).